# How to assign nil if network call returns error using Combine

Tags: swift, promise, future, combine

I have a variable with default value. And make a network call to get the value from server. If it returns some error, then I want to make the variable to `nil`. How can I do this with `Future`, `Promise`, `Combine`?

[Asynchronous Programming with Futures and Promises in Swift with Combine Framework](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-programming-with-future-and-promise-in-swift-with-combine-framework/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the error with a nil value fails because your Future emits an `Int` value. Change it to an optional `Int?`:

```
var count: Int? = 0

    let future = Future<Int?, Error> { promise in
        promise(.failure(DummyError()))
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()

    init(){
        future
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main) //Getting error
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .assign(to: &$count)
    }
```

and `assign(to: &)` works only with `@Published` values.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I added `@Published` for the `count` variable and now I'm unable to use `assign(to: &)`. It shows "Cannot convert value of type Int? to expected arg type Published<Int?>.publisher

Comment: Using `assign(to:on:)` won't gonna work like that, since you need to store the `AnyCancellable` returned by the subscription and that operator also has a memory leak unfortunately, hence Apple released `assign(to:)` on iOS 14.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I stand corrected.

Comment: @arunsiva see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Output` of `future` is `Int`, so you cannot replace errors with `nil`, you'd need to replace them with an `Int`, since the `Output` of upstream publishers and the input of downstream operators must always match.

You can resolve the issue by mapping the `future`'s `Output` to `Optional<Int>`, then you can replace errors with `nil`.

```
future
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .map(Optional.some)
        .replaceError(with: nil)
        .assign(to: &$count)
```

Also, `assign(to:)` takes a `Published.Publisher` as its input, so you need to make your `count` `@Published` and pass in its `Publisher` using `$count` to `assign`.

So change the declaration to `@Publised var count: Int? = 0`.